# Confusion about setFollowRedirects()

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I have an android app where I am requesting API calls using *HttpURLConnection* and the *GET* method.

In the code(pre-written), there is a line,

> HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);

I have observed that rarely, there is an **SSLException Error** and the token is not generated.
If I set the "**setFollowRedirects to true**", the error seems to go away.

I tried to understand what exactly is the meaning of this and *if it is really the reason why SSLException error goes away.*

Being aware of the fact that there can be many other parameters, the issue doesnot occur regularly. It might be occuring when there is more traffic or the network is slow.

I wish to understand what exactly this follow Redirect means and how is it impacting the api requests.

P.S.: Please dont send me links. I have already googled it. :P